# How do you add unit tests for an nginx module?

Tags: c, unit-testing, nginx

I'm writing a custom module for nginx.  I would like to add unit tests to this project, but I don't see a way to add them into the nginx build process.  How do I add a new "check" target to the nginx build so that my tests build and run?

Ideally, I would like to use the [Check](https://libcheck.github.io/check/) unit test framework, but I'm open to others.

Comment: were you able to write or find units tests for nginx module ?? currently i have a custom module for which unit testing is required ..

Answer (score 0):

Tests for nginx are located in separate [repository](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx-tests) and written in Perl (including tests for particular modules). I can suggest you to investigate some easy test examples like [ngx_http_empty_gif_module](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx-tests/file/tip/empty_gif.t) or [ngx_http_stub_status_module](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx-tests/file/tip/stub_status.t) and write your own test suit for your module. For more details about nginx tests you can look into [README](http://hg.nginx.org/nginx-tests/file/tip/README).

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work for unit tests since I can't get perl code to directly call C functions inside of nginx.

Comment: Yes, if you want to call C functions inside your code than there is no simple way to add tests. Can you tell more about your module and what would you like to test?